# I want to Show Video on ASP.NET Core MVC View from SQL Database

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-core, video, memorystream

so basically I have stored my video files using this below logic to my SQL server database table:

```
using (var dataStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(dataStream);
                VideoSegment video = new VideoSegment
                {
                    VideoData = dataStream.ToArray(),
                    ProfileidForVideoSegment = userprofileid.Id
                };
                Context.VideoSegments.Add(video);
                Context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

So using this above code my data stored to table perfectly in form varbinary(MAX) but now I want to retrieve this video data to show video playing on my asp.net core website. I have searched a lot for this but every time I found solutions related to aspx, simple asp.net MVC. but still searching for ASP.NET Core MVC website because I want to show video In my asp.net core MVC not simple asp.net MVC website.
So please tell me a solution to how to do this work. Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: See following "ASP.NET Core video tutorials" on webpage : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?force_isolation=true&view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: @jdweng can you tell me in which tutorial I will find material related to my question???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class VideoSegment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] VideoData { get; set; }
}
```

Create.cshtml:

```
@model VideoSegment

<h1>Create</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="VideoData" class="control-label"></label>
                <input name="file" type="file" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="VideoData" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

VideoSegmentsController:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm]IFormFile file)
{
    using (var dataStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(dataStream);
        VideoSegment video = new VideoSegment
        {
            VideoData = dataStream.ToArray(),
        };
        _context.VideoSegment.Add(video);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```

When you add the videosegment successfully, you will redirect to Index action and display the video:

Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<VideoSegment>

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VideoData)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <video autoplay controls src="/Home/SampleVideoStream?id=@item.Id"></video>
            </td>           
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

VideoSegmentsController:

```
public class VideoSegmentsController : Controller
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _context;

    public VideoSegmentsController(YourDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: VideoSegments
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.VideoSegment.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _context;
    public HomeController(YourDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult SampleVideoStream(int id)
    {
        var data = _context.VideoSegment.Find(id);
        return File(data.VideoData, "video/mp4");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Rena it worked for me perfectly. I am really very surprised that which solutions google and different website suggest was literally very ugly and not related to ASP.NET Core. but public IActionResult SampleVideoStream(int id)
    {
        var data = _context.VideoSegment.Find(id);
        return File(data.VideoData, "video/mp4");
    }
lines of code have solved my issue.
Thanks again, Rena

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to stream a varbinary directly out of a SQL server table. But there is a roadblock you need to overcome.

First you need a way to access a `DbDataReader`. This way you can reuse the same infrastructure as EF Core, so you don't need to manage the connection yourself. Since this bit isn't supported, it might break in future.

```cs
// Based on https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/16188163c24b1c803c4d694e9222a2f717fcb376/src/EFCore.Relational/Extensions/RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.cs#L211
public static Task<RelationalDataReader> ExecuteReaderRawAsync(this DatabaseFacade db, string sql, IEnumerable<object> parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var dependencies = ((IDatabaseFacadeDependenciesAccessor)db).Dependencies as IRelationalDatabaseFacadeDependencies;
    var cmd = dependencies.RawSqlCommandBuilder
        .Build(sql, parameters);

    return cmd.RelationalCommand
        .ExecuteReaderAsync(new RelationalCommandParameterObject(
            dependencies.RelationalConnection,
            cmd.ParameterValues,
            null,
            ((IDatabaseFacadeDependenciesAccessor)db).Context,
            dependencies.CommandLogger
        ), cancellationToken);
}
```

Now you can select a varbinary column as a stream;

```cs
using var reader = await context.Database.ExecuteReaderRawAsync(
    "select VideoData from VideoSegment where Id = {0}", 
    new object[] { Id });

if (await reader.ReadAsync()){
    using var stream = reader.DbDataReader.GetStream(0);
    // TODO copy stream to the response.
}
```

Copying a stream into a database column is slightly easier. Though if you are using EF Core to insert the row, you have to do that first.

```cs
var streamParm = new SqlParameter()
{
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarBinary,
    Value = stream
};
await context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolatedAsync(
    $"update VideoSegment set VideoData = {streamParm} where id = {Id}");
```

Comment: One should use Read() instead of ReadAsync() because async currently runs extremely slow. See https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/593. And it is possible to use IQueryable.CreateDbCommand()

Comment: That's because the current sql server client is synchronous, but runs in another thread. This advice might be inaccurate for other database drivers. Interesting, I didn't notice that new method in EF Core 5. So you could `context.VideoSegments.Where(..).Select(v => v.VideoData).CreateDbCommand(); ... .ExecuteReaderAsync();` then read the stream from the results, similar to the above.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet extracts varbinary(max) data as a stream in a fast way:

```
DbCommand cmd = Context.VideoSegments.Where(vs => vs.Id == id).Select(vs => vs.VideoData).CreateDbCommand();
if (cmd.Connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
    await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync();
}
await using DbDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SingleResult & CommandBehavior.SingleRow &
    CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess & CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
//if (await reader.ReadAsync()) // very slow!
if (reader.Read())
{
    var stm = reader.GetStream(0); // zero-based column index
    return stm;
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

and in controller:

```
if (dataStm != null)
{
    return File(dataStm, mimeDataType);
}
else
{
    return NoContent();
}
```